# WPF lock control positions during animation

Tags: wpf, animation

I have a 2 column grid with a view rendered in each one. I have animation that reduces the width of the 1st column to expose the contents of the 2nd column and vice versa. During the animation, I do not want the buttons that are in the view that is being reduced in size to constantly have their position readjusted as the column shrinks in size. Bad effect. Is there a way to lock the position of the controls while the animation is in progress?
Thanks
Harold

Comment: Maybe you should animate Width and Height accordingly...

Comment: Not sure what that would do... animating the width currently makes for a nice swiping effect except for the reshuffling of the controls.